# Fatal error: Call to undefined function protect()

Tags: php

Getting this

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function protect() in C:\wamp\www\Game\registration.php on line 25" when trying to register.

Here's the apparent culprit

```
$username = protect($_POST['username']);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `protect()` is not a native PHP function. You need to have that defined somewhere and included in that file before you can use it.

Comment: Your title and question have two completely different errors - one where the function isn't defined, and one where it's defined twice...

Comment: Now that you've fixed your question title, the answer is simple: define `function protect()` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERS BY JOHN CONDE AND NIET THE DARK ABSOL

protect() is not a native PHP function. You need to have that defined somewhere and included in that file before you can use it. –  John Conde 5 mins ago

Your title and question have two completely different errors - one where the function isn't defined, and one where it's defined twice... –  Niet the Dark Absol